# Which programming lang.s are used for ui of os?

Tags: linux, programming

Which programming languages are used  for the part of the os which  user interacts with (the application?), for instance the task bar (on linux ,macosx or windows), start button, desktop etc. ?

Comment: It depends, why do you assume there is *one* language?

Comment: I just wanted to make my own os ..so I wanted to know the languages used

Comment: Then you are asking completely the wrong question of quite the wrong audience on the wrong WWW site.

Comment: Wrong ... could you elaborate? @JdeBP could you elaborate please?

Comment: You need to find an audience of _systems_ and _applications programmers_, with knowledge of Windows, MacOS, and other operating systems, not an audience of _Unix and Linux users_.

Comment: @neppro Note that the GUI is just a very tiny part of the OS (in fact, some might say that it's not really part of the OS as such at all). If you truly want to start writing your own operating system (Unix-like or otherwise), you will have to start with writing a kernel. Then you will have to port or rewrite run-time libraries and compilers and other tools. _Then_ you can start to think about what type of graphical interface you need to support.  I know of no language (apart from toy languages) that _can't_ be used for writing UIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C, C++, C#, Python, Ruby, Java/Kotlin, HTML, CSS, QML, Pascal and others

On Windows often use C#, on Linux - C++

More information about GUI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits

And user can use OS without any graphical interface